# Vim - g command for deleting characters in specific columns

Tags: vim

I want to delete 5 characters starting from column 11 in the whole file.
When I type

```
11|5x
```

it works for the line the cursor is on.
But when I type

```
:g/.*/11|5x
```

the editor closes.

How should I use the g command properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Understanding Vi(m) modes is key to mastering it.*

The `|` command to jump to a screen column is a *normal mode* command, but the `:global` command takes *Ex commands*. The `:normal` Ex commands interprets following arguments as normal mode commands (with `!`: without considering mappings (which is safer)):

```
:g/.*/normal! 11|5x
```

PS: A shorter "match anywhere" pattern for `:g` is `^` instead of `.*`.

Comment: I found even shorter match that selects all lines - no pattern!

`:g//command`

Comment: @tarsis: `:g//` uses whatever search pattern you used most recently, so it is not a reliable way to match every line.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
:g/./norm! 11|5x
```

you need the `normal`

Answer (score 0):

The normal `|` motion bring the cursor to a *screen* column, which may not be expected when you have multi-column characters like `<Tab>` in a line.

Substitution globally like below can avoid this problem:

`%s/\%10c.\{5}/`, in which `\%10c` matches the column position of the 10th character.